# Ionic AngularJS ng-value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having some troubble with an ng-value set on an input.
I need to pass the userID through to the input, which can then be sent through once the form is clicked.

Here is my html

```html
   <div ng-repeat="chats in chat">
 <form ng-submit="submit()" id="login-form1" class="list">
 <button style="">
      <ion-item style="background:rgb(243,243,243)" class="item-avatar" id="chat-list-item1">
      <img style="width:100%;height:auto;" ng-src="https://www.socialnetwk.com/media/{{chats.media_file_format}}/{{chats.post_id}}{{chats.uid}}.{{chats.media_file_format}}" />
        <h2>{{chats.firstname}} {{chats.lastname}}</h2>
        <p>Hey whats been going on</p>
      </ion-item>
      <input style="" type="text" ng-model="data.userID" ng-value="{{chats.userID}}" value="{{chats.userID}}" />
</button>
      </form>
  </div>
```

And my controller

```js
.controller('chatCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.session_id= sessionStorage.getItem('session_id');
    var sid = $scope.session_id;
    if($scope.session_id == null){
        $state.go('login');
    }
    else {
        var cload = 'https://m.socialnetwk.com/home/app/chat_load.php';
        $http.post(cload, {id : $scope.session_id}).then(function (res){
            $scope.chat = res.data;
        });
        $scope.submit = function(){

        alert($scope.data.userID);
        };
    }
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this::

```
<input id="searchType" type="text" name="searchTyp" ng-model="data.userID" ng-init="data.userID=chats.userID" style="display: none;>
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: That seemed to half work. Its showing the value in the view. However on submit its not being passed through

Comment: are you getting userID in alert?

Comment: Yes, however its undefined. Yet on inspect element the ID is passed into the input

Comment: i have added name attribute which was missiong...can you check now

Comment: Tried that, no luck either

Comment: I tried `      <input id="searchType" type="text" name="searchTyp" ng-model="data.userID" ng-init="data.userID='{{chats.userID}}'" style="display: none;">
`
And that seems to work, the value is in the html. But on submit the value is just the text {{chats.userID}}

Comment: <input id="searchType" type="text" name="searchTyp" ng-model="data.userID" ng-init="data.userID=chats.userID" style="display: none;">try this we almost there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133192/discussion-between-pankaj-badukale-and-casper-round).

Comment: Update, turns out it was only loading the last value of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, you can not combine ng-value with ng-model in an input[text]:

> It can also be used to achieve one-way binding of a given expression
>   to an input element such as an input[text] or a textarea, when that
>   element does not use ngModel.

### Edit:

I just noticed the ng-repeat. 
Use the ng-model as an array of values. E.G. : data['inputId]. So you have one ng-model and different values. There would be no conflicts with the ng-repeat.

Comment: Use the ng-model as an array of values. E.G. : `data['inputId]`. So you have one ng-model and different values. There will be no conflicts with the ng-repeat.